# Powershell - Hide error message from displaying, occuring on line 3

Tags: excel, powershell, com

I need help hiding the below error message that occurs when Powershell doesn't find an Excel instance running (or a means of somehow circumventing it):

> Get-Process : Cannot find a process with the name "excel". Verify the
>   process name and call the cmdlet again. At run.ps1:3 char:24
>   + $before = @(get-process <<<<  excel | %{$_.Id} ) 
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (excel:String) [Get-Process], ProcessCommandException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoProcessFoundForGivenName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetProcessCommand

Line 3-5 of my code is as follows:

```
$before = @(get-process excel | %{$_.Id} ) 
$excel=new-object -com excel.application
$excelId = get-process excel | %{$_.Id} | ?{$before -notcontains $_}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could do the following?

```
Get-Process Excel -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %{ $_.Id }
```

Or this?

```
Get-Process | ?{ $_.name -eq "excel" } | %{ $_.Id }
```

Comment: @methuselah What does the modified line 3 of your code look like?

Comment: @methuselah Which one did you try? Do you get the same error message as before?